# NHibernate NonUniqueObjectException when updating an existing record

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am maintaing an existing application where I needed for performance issues to point NHibernate to a view to get away from it producing outer joins. This is ok, and I get an entity back populated with data.

Now, this object is then updated in C# and calls on Update, which is a generic method in the C# code used by a number of other repository classes. When this Update method is called, I am getting an error message:
       "NHibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

It points to a nested object inside the entity object, but I am unclear as to how to resolve this. I don't want to change the update method in case this impacts classes that use it.

If I need to revert back from using a view to get data, is it possible to set in the mapping config to force NHibernate to use equi-joins rather than left outer joins?

I am not that familiar with NHibernate, and so any guidance/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A `session.Merge(entity)` would be solution here. Working with detached objects is described here:

[9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)

small cite:

> ...
>
> The last case can be avoided by using `Merge(Object o)`. This method
>   copies the state of the given object onto the persistent object with
>   the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will be loaded. The method returns the
>   persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved or does not
>   exist in the database, NHibernate will save it and return it as a
>   newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance does not
>   become associated with the session. In most applications with detached
>   objects, you need both methods, *SaveOrUpdate()* and `Merge()`.

Other words, calling `Merge(entity)` should solve this issue, and properly resolve conflicts related to *"passed objects"* vs *"session (loaded) objects"*

Comment: Can you please clarify something for me. I have a repo layer that calls a view and passes the data up to the logic layer to then update the data. In the logic layer the updated data then calls the generic update method in another repo to then update the database. What I don't want to do is to change the generic update repo method in case it breaks something else. Can you please reply on my expanded point

Comment: You can try your best to find new better way.. or simply live with the world (NHibernate) as is. In case of the second approach, read my link to doc. Detached objects are a bit fragile stuff. They must be re-attached and often even merged. The reason is, NHibernate could already load the "same/original" object - into the new/second session.And because we pass object from different session (loaded via view) we have to either convert *(well, **bind**)* changes into objects in the second session, or merge the detached ones. Google for handling detached objects "nhibernate detached objects update"

Comment: Another try to explain that: https://ayende.com/blog/4282/nhibernate-cross-session-operations and this is about JAVA but the core is exactly the same http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate